# Is there a difference between cog and sprocket?

Tags: discussion

We have two tags: cog and sprocket

neither are described. As far as I know, cog and sprocket are the same thing, but there may be a technical distinction that I'm not aware of.

Should I make this a question: *What is the difference between a sprocket and cog?*

If none, should we make the two synonyms?

Comment: AFAIK one's American word, the other is a European/English word for the same thing.    But everyone uses Cassette for multiple of them, and Block is only used in the UK amongst older riders.

Comment: Ok, merged them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically...  cogs are the *teeth* on a sprocket or gear. But the word also means "cogwheel".

A cogwheel is... basically any wheel with teeth (cogs).

A gear is a wheel with cogs that mesh with the gears of another wheel.

A sprocket is a wheel with cogs that mesh with a chain (or belt or tape or film or whatever). Just like a pulley, but with teeth that mesh somehow.

A typical bicycle doesn't have any *gears* on it, just cogwheels that are sprockets.

On the site: I think "sprocket", "cog" and "gear" are all used to mean the same thing and merging those tags would make sense.

UPDATE: [cog](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cog) is now merged into [sprocket](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprocket) (with synonym).

Comment: Q: "what gear were you in at the time of the accident?"  
A: "black Raphla compression top,  Castalri bib tights, and white Zoom shoes"      based on this old chestnut    http://lawvibe.com/the-stupidest-things-lawyers-and-witnesses-say-in-a-court-of-law/   about the 6th one down.

Comment: @Criggie I thought all that was "kit"? Are you telling me people use "gear" to describe that, too?

Comment: Are the toothed wheels in a freewheel cogwheels, or do they have yet another name :)

Comment: People are using "gears" to talk about gearing in general, so I wouldn't make it a synonym of the cog-sprocket cluster. :-)

Comment: We might want to rename "gears" to "gearing" and add a redirect synonym.

Comment: @Móż The toothed wheels in a freewheel are cogwheels, and are also sprockets (sprocket being the specific type of cogwheel which applies to them).

Answer (score 3):

In wikipedia, [Cog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cog) is defined as

> A cog is a tooth of a gear or cogwheel or *the gear itself*.

Emphasis added.

[Sprocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprocket) is defined as

> A sprocket or sprocket-wheel is a profiled wheel with teeth [...] *that mesh with a chain*, track or other perforated or indented material. The name 'sprocket' applies generally to any wheel upon which radial *projections engage a chain* passing over it. It is distinguished from a gear in that sprockets are never meshed together directly, and differs from a pulley in that sprockets have teeth and pulleys are smooth.
>
> Sprockets are used in bicycles ...

Emphasis added.

A cog is not a sprocket. If we are to retain the *Cog* tag then it should be made a synonym of *Sprocket*. While that is technically inaccurate, it would support how non-technical people use the terms.

Comment: OK, so sprocket should be the main entry and cog a synonym. Sounds good to me! Someone with mod-authority, please make it so!

Comment: If I understand the definitions, all sprockets are cogs, and *some* cogs are sprockets. I agree that "sprocket" is probably the better tag to stick around, with "cog" merged in as a synonym. But I think it's a good idea to give people another day or two to notice this post and comment before we make it so.

Comment: @freiheit - no I think that's incorrect according to the definition. "Cogs" only interact with other "cogs" (or gears); while "sprockets" only interact with chains. Since our sprockets only touch chain, they are sprockets and not cogs. But this is prescriptive use and bicyclists have their own lingo.

Comment: @RoboKaren Yeah, but the purpose isn't defining these things just right; the purpose is getting things that are about the same topic tagged the same way. And cyclists definitely use both "sprocket" and "cog" to refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Within BMX, "sprocket" always means a front gear ring with either a single hole (bolt drive) or spline drive, the kind that one-piece and freestyle three-piece cranks use.

I think it counts for something that this usage is ubiquitous and well-understood in BMX while cog versus sprocket is ambiguous elsewhere. Personally I never use "sprocket" to mean anything other than the BMX usage for this reason, although I wouldn't go so far as to say other usage is wrong. It's all arbitrary, but I feel disregarding the BMX terminology outright shows limited perspective.

Comment: From what you say, I'm getting that a BMXer would understand *sprocket* to mean the front ring. What do they call the rear sprocket / cog / thingy?

Comment: A front ring that's bolt drive or spline drive. If it's got chainring bolts then more erudite BMXers call it a chainring. BMX-oriented wholesalers and retailers follow those usages too. Rear gears are freewheel if it's a freewheel, cog if it's a cassette cog, or driver if it's a one piece driver, as in most real street/park/dirt bikes.